# SharePoint 2010 performance blocking issue at particular time

Tags: sharepoint-server, content-database, performance

After some changes, deployed this week, SharePoint 2010 can't operate properly, throwing Timeout error for any action. It appears at a particular time - **9pm**. All actions, which affect database fail with Timeout error. But from the morning **till 9PM it is functioning properly and stable**. 
Is there a way to determine which particular timer job or web part or workflow or event receiver are blocking the database access? I'm just doing improvements for the system, so I'm not very familiar with the complete infrastructure.
Reviewing the sharepoint logs didn't help that much.
Any help or suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Is there any sandbox solution deployed?

Comment: there are some user solutions deployed, but how it could affect performance? The question is if someone experienced a similar issue and how it can be monitored / investigated. Sorry if my question wasn't clear.

Comment: You have backups configured to run at that time? Check what session and  query block the database: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/06/sql-server-quickest-way-to-identify-blocking-query-and-resolution-dirty-solution/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @ChristianAzcon , I'll try that. There was also another issue, server had only 4Giga RAM installed, which was not enough. According to the documentation, it must have 8Giga for production use.

Comment: moreover, there was a complete database backup starting at 9PM, so we've shifted the schedule to 2AM, and also increased RAM to 8Giga hopefully this will resolve the performance issue.